# Can there be a Shared Extension across Multiple Overridden Visualforce Pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller, controller-extension, extension

I would like to know if its possible to share a common extension class across multiple Visualforce Pages which use different standard Controllers.

For Eg., I've VF_A Page which overrides default Contact Page and VF_B Page which overrides Lead Page. I need a common functionality to be implemented in both Contact and Lead Pages. Right now, I've two extensions Ext_A ad Ext_B to implement the same functionality.

What I'm looking for is, if there is a way to use a single Extension Ext_A_B to be used in both the pages. Its possible to use the same extension by finding out the `Object.getKeyPrefix()`.

I'm not sure if its the right way to proceed? Or is there any other way to go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes it is possible since standard controller extensions require just a constructor with a standard controller as a param

```
public class Ext_A_B {

    public Ext_A_B(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

        sObjectType sot = controller.getRecord().getsObjectType();

        if (sot == Lead.sObjectType){
           // LEAD LOGIC
        }
        else if (sot == Contact.sObjectType){
           // CONTACT LOGIC
        }
    }

}
```