# Visualforce page sharing same extension instance

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

[From here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12385/can-there-be-a-shared-extension-across-multiple-overridden-visualforce-pages) I understand that it is possible to add multiple pages to a single extension but I want to take it further and not generate a new extension instance when the other page is loaded but keep the values that were set.
I need to share some 15-20 fields between two pages and using a querystring seems redundant and I can't use a salesforce sObject because I gather the data from a GET request and it is not stored in SalesForce. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible as long as you use setRedircet=false in your pageReference. Session will be maintained and you will have access to all the data.